# Filling out a CRC card

Tags: uml

This is a CRC card I have to fill out. I know how to fill out everything, except I don't know the difference between "associated use case" and "collaborators." Also, how would i define the relationships? Thanks. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Collaborators are other classes that work in some way with the referenced one. Eg. in a banking context `Credit Card` and `ATM` will be collaborators.

The related use case are those where this class will take a role. E.g. the `ATM` in `Withdraw Money`.

Relationships define how other classes are related (as property). E.g. `Customer` has a `Credit Card`.